# Reading and writing binary file in C language

Tags: c, file

I tried to read and write fild in C but it failed. It partly worked, but the original file and the output file is not same.
I tried to read and write bmp file.

```
FILE* openFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");                      
FILE* writeFile = fopen(strcat(argv[1], ".cpd"), "wb");     
fseek(openFile, 0, SEEK_END);                               
long size = ftell(openFile);                                
char* bin = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));       
rewind(openFile);                                           
fwrite(bin, size, 1, writeFile);

//closefile, free, ...
```

Comment: There's no `fread` in your code.As a side note, `strcat(argv[1], ".cpd")` is a crash waiting to happen.

Comment: Where do you think you are reading the file?...

Comment: the output file exist but it's not same with original file.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. You also need to check if `fopen` fails.

Comment: Note that `fseek(openFile, 0, SEEK_END);` on a binary file is undefined behavior in strictly conforming C code:  ["Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream..."](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268)  More importantly, it will also fail for files larger than 2 GB for any platform where `long` is 32 bits (such as 64-bit Windows...)

Answer (score 1):

You should add reading the original file somewhere in your code:

```
FILE* openFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");                      
FILE* writeFile = fopen(strcat(argv[1], ".cpd"), "wb");     
fseek(openFile, 0, SEEK_END);                               
long size = ftell(openFile);                                
char* bin = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));       
rewind(openFile);                                           
fread(bin, size, 1, openFile);   // <-- here, for example
fwrite(bin, size, 1, writeFile);
```

Comment: @LPs `fopen`, `fseek`, `ftell`, `rewind`, `fread` and `fwrite` may fail as well. so what?

Comment: So...correct your proposed solution with all those checks....